# How can I use float in stylesheet with a true way?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to right the text as float(It is gonna be next to the table and then when the letters get bottom they are gonna continue from just below the table) but when I do that table is going center.How can I fix that?
[image]

Here is the code for html:

```html
<html lang="en">
<header>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Page</title>
</header>

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <table border="2">
        <tr>
          <th>MAINPAGE</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>BLOG</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>CONTACT</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <p>
      kajnaldkfgldkfmlgmsdlşngskdgfnşsdjnvfkdsjşfnvsjvnjnknnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnkjdfnvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvdk jh bouıpmekfrmlrfmwewpewpemwpmdwwefmwefpwoepwelwmepwoermwp wjfnwkeflwekfmwlfkmlwfkmlwfmklwfmklwfkmlwmflwmelfmwelfkmwlfmkwlfmkw
      wkjefwnkfnw meıwoerıjwoejrwonf wowıj fowıjeowjrow erjw eojw eorjıwroj
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the code for css:

```css
header {
  background-image: url("images/logo.jpg");
  width: %100;
  height: 250px;
  background-repeat: no-background-position: top center;
}

div {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

table {
  border-style: double;
  padding: .2em;
  height: 170px;
  width: 240px;
  margin: 200px left;
  margin: 2em top;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  position: relative;
}

tr {
  border="5";
  border-style: solid;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

body {
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: .2em;
  margin-left: .5em;
  margin-top: .5em;
  margin-bottom: 50em;
  float: right;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: (1) Write valid HTML. Use a [validator](https://validator.nu/). Don't put your `/`s in the wrong place

Comment: (2) Don't use tables for layout

Comment: (3) Write valid CSS. Use [a validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Comment: Actually I do not about using validator and my page do not have "http" so it is not getting accepted.I am little confused and  which place I used  "\" wrongly if you said I would be happy.thank you for your answer by the way.@Quentin

Comment: Click on the drop down menu that says "Address" and change it to "File Upload" then validate that way.

Comment: Thank you  I am gonna try with that way.So when I used float for table text is still going left could you say that which way I could used instead of table for mainpage and contact?@Quentin

Answer (score 2):

Leaving aside the numerous syntax errors in your HTML and CSS:

If you want the table to float in the sea of words that are in the paragraph then you need to **float the table** and not the paragraph.

```css
table {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2em 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A
        <td>B
    <tr>
        <td>C
        <td>D
 </table>
 
 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In pretium, orci ac dapibus scelerisque, mauris felis mollis ante, ut placerat ex nunc eu turpis. Nullam vel purus eu est fringilla luctus ut tempus elit. Donec a justo sed nisl viverra blandit sed eget tellus. Aenean leo nunc, tempor in elementum a, vulputate sit amet orci. In felis enim, dapibus vel ultrices eget, dapibus eu felis. Sed mollis, est id commodo ullamcorper, ex velit convallis enim, nec tristique nibh sem at lectus. Donec at orci ac tortor maximus ullamcorper. Etiam rhoncus magna eu ligula placerat iaculis. Nam ac risus lectus. Praesent viverra ipsum fringilla interdum consectetur. Proin sed felis odio. Pellentesque facilisis finibus quam, ut venenatis lorem condimentum ac. Vivamus sagittis diam risus.
```